# Navigation Drawer Fragment cut off at top

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm using the Navigation Drawer Template on android and I'm also using fragments. Whenever there is a fragment, the action cuts off the fragment's top. I haven't changed the default code other than adding in the fragment. How do you get the fragment to load below the action bar?

picture of the problem:

*update
Now it looks like this
[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.slidemenu.TestFragment"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TESTTEST"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**app bar main xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.android.slidemenu.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you paste your xml layout?

Comment: good example here :https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/tree/master/app/src/main/res/layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FrameLayout` needs to be below the `Toolbar`, and inside the `CoordinatorLayout`. Try to restructure like so.

Include the "main contents" in the `DrawerLayout`. Then add the `FrameLayout` after the `AppBarLayout` (or include other views if Fragments aren't needed).

The secret line that "pushes" down the FrameLayout is this line

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

---

drawer layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/nav_content"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.slidemenu.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I added the framelayout where you said and it fixed the problem of the fragment being on top of the actionbar but the top of the fragment is still being blocked.

Comment: @T.Yang You can wrap the AppBarLayout and FrameLayout in a Vertical LinearLayout so they don't overlap

Comment: The updated answer and wrapping the layouts both work

Comment: If you had a collapsing toolbar, this answer is more preferred

Answer (score 2):

Put the `FrameLayout` inside the `CoordinatorLayout`, after the `AppBarLayout`.

EDIT: Try removing the `android:fitsSystemWindows=true`.

Comment: No. changed answer.

Comment: The top of the fragment is still blocked.

Comment: Still has the same problem

Comment: @T.Yang Did you remove all of the instances in which it appears?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `false` instead of removing it did the trick for me. Thx **amitairos** for the hint ;).